# Are the endpoints included in a definite integral?

Tags: integration

The integral $\int _{\:0}^{\:\frac{\pi }{2}}\:1+\left(-sinx\right)+\left(-sinx\right)^2+...dx$ is a geometric sereis which can be expressed as $\int _0^{\frac{\:\pi }{\:2}}\:\frac{1}{1-\left(-sinx\right)}dx$.

But this is only valid if $|r|<1$. In the given bounds in the integral, $\sin{x}$ is precisely in between $0$ and $-1$, but at $\sin(90)$, it is actually equal to $-1$ which does not suit $|r|<1$

It always thought that the endpoints were inclusive in a definite integral but that seems to lead to contradictions here.

Comment: What happens at any one particular point never matters for a definite integral (for an otherwise integrable function)

Comment: $\sin (90)$ is $1$. Anyway, the value at  the end points have no effect on the  value of the definite integral.

Comment: This is an example of an [improper integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral).

Comment: I don't understand - so is it included or not? It seems yes it is included by it has "no effect on the value", so it's not included at the same time?...

Comment: @user71207 as the integrand is not bounded you have to integrate the function from $[0,\varepsilon]$ and take limit of $ \varepsilon \rightarrow \pi/2 $

Comment: And if the function was bounded then you can ignore the value at the end point

Comment: The question is meaningless and I'll give an example why we phrased it that way because it's true for any point not just the endpoints. Consider $f(x) = 3$ and $$g(x) =\begin{cases} f(x) & x\neq 1\\ 5 & x=1\end{cases}$$ Both of the integrals $$\int_0^2 f(x)dx = \int_0^2 g(x)dx = 6$$ even though the second one "excludes" the point $x=1$. If the integrals take on the same value whether or not any single point is "included", then inclusion is a bit of a meaningless thing to discuss.

Comment: @NinadMunshi In the definition of integration we require the function to be bounded otherwise supremum and infimum won't make sense which should be the primary concern of this question

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi Boundedness is not required for integrability.

Comment: @NinadMunshi atleast you should look at the definition of the integral, what will you say the supremum of the function if it is not bounded. I think you meant that we can define an improper integral

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi as a very simple counterexample, could you tell me what $$\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}$$ evaluates to?

Comment: @NinadMunshi That can be evaluated by integrating the function in $[\varepsilon,1]$ and take limits.And that is not a counterexample, if still not satisfied see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/817806/697953)

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi you are probably referring to Darboux integrabilitiy with the sup and inf. Boundedness is not a requirement, you can apply the same definition to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ and prove it is integrable by restricitng the refinements on the partitions to never touch $0$. This does not have to be a limiting process as you describe. Anyway, feel free to open a chat window, I don't want to clutter OP's post any further to clear up misconceptions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119803/discussion-between-aditya-dwivedi-and-ninad-munshi).

Comment: $$\int_{0}^{\pi /2}\left[1+\left(-\sin x\right)+\left(-\sin x\right)^2+\ldots \,\right]dx=$$
$$=\frac{\pi}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\pi /2}(-\sin x)^n\,dx=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\sqrt{\pi } (-1)^n \Gamma \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}{n \Gamma \left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}+\frac{\pi }{2}=1$$