# Example that a necessary condition is not sufficient. Riemann integrable

Tags: calculus, analysis, examples-counterexamples, riemann-integration

Form what I understand a necessary condition for Riemann integrable function is it must be bounded, and a sufficient condition can be that the function is if a bounded function has finitely many discontinuities.

Can someone provide an example where it showed that Riemann integrable function MUST be bounded?

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/817501/prove-that-integrable-implies-bounded?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: @lulu yes this clear it up a bit, but is there an example with real numbers not just u,v? or is that enough to prove it?